# show mysql result using php while loop without table

Tags: php, mysql, list, loops

I list mysql result in 4 horizontal `<UL>` and `<li>` with this code :

```
    echo"<div>";
    $c = 1; // change to $c = 0 
    $media = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . "$prefix" . "screen where id=\"$id\" order by id desc limit 16");
    while ($cms = mysql_fetch_assoc($media)) {

      if (!($c%4)) echo ($c!=0 ? "</ul>" : "")."<ul>";

        echo "<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>\n";

        $c++;
            }

        echo "</ul></div>\n";

      for ($cnt=$c;$cnt%4>0;$cnt++);
```

The HTML output from the above code is:

```
<UL>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
</UL>
<UL>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
</UL>
<UL>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
</UL>
<UL>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
</UL>
<UL>
    <li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>
</UL>
```

This is incorrect. Each `<ul>` should contain 4 `<li>`.

**Update**:
I changed $c = 0  and remove top `<ul>` is now worked !

Answer (score 0):

Set `$c = 0` at the beginning. Loops tend to be zero-based—and your usage of modulo requires this.

Your code is also very hard to read. Maybe consider spaces between operators and indenting blocks?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you want. Could you please post your desired HTML output?

Comment: i found problem ! remove <UL> after TOP <DIV> no worked . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your $c = 1 in the top. Since this is 1 at first, it will only print out 3 more (1+1+1+1 = 4, 4 % 4 = 0) and then the count is zero, and will now print 4.
This little fix should do the trick.

```
$c = 0;
$media = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . "$config_ccms_prefix" . "screen where id=\"$id\" order by id desc limit 16"); 

while ($cms = mysql_fetch_assoc($media)) { 
    if (!($c % 4))
        echo "<ul>"; 

    echo "<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"></a></li>\n"; 

    if(!($c++ % 4))
        echo "</ul>";
} 
echo "</div>\n"; 
for ($cnt = $c; $cnt % 4 > 0; $cnt++);
```

(notice the $c is set to 0 at start and the echo  and $c++ is moved to the end of the loop body)

Comment: i forgot put `<div>` and `<ul>` in top! so your code not work for 4 `<UL>` `</UL> in each `<UL>` 4 li `</UL>`